# Instanbul/Nyc only picking up some files

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I tried to set up Istanbul/Nyc/Mocha for test coverage for my project and although I was able to run Nyc successfully, I am only able to see some files being picked up for test coverage not all the .ts files that I have.

So when I run

```
npm run coverage
```

I get

```
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                   | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
-----------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files              |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 |                  
 develop-potta         |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 |                  
  swagger.ts           |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 1                
 develop-potta/models  |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 |                  
  students.ts          |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 1                
  swaggerDefinition.ts |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 1                
 develop-potta/routes  |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 |                  
  routescontroller.ts  |       0 |      100 |     100 |       0 | 4-5
```

This only covers about 50% of my code base. For example I have a develop-potta/DBConnection/OracleConnection.ts which is also a ts file which isn't being picked up by my script. I am unable to figure out why? Could it be a certain naming convention? Could it be that I didn't export those modules?

Answer (score 2):

Typescript + mocha + nyc can be picky. Especially the all: true setting messes up the coverage a lot. But as you mention it's hard to bring it cover all files. My template repo covers those cases. Maybe it can help you.

https://github.com/Flowkap/typescript-node-template

If you're only interested in coverage check the .ncyrc.yml and mocharc.yml as well as the call config in package.json. VsCode launch configs also included.